# Why node.js does not recognize document.GetElementById? It says 'ReferenceError: document is not defined'. What could I do?

Tags: javascript, html

```
//This is My HTML

<div class="container">

        <h1>To Do List</h1>

        <input id="inputField" type="text"><button id="toDoList">+</button>

        <div class="to-dos"></div>
    </div>


//This is my javascript


let toDoListInput = document.getElementById('toDoList');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
toDoListInput.addEventListener('click', function(){
     let paragraph = document.createElement('p')
     paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
     toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
     inputField.value = "";
})
```

Comment: Node does not have a `document` object.

Comment: node.js runs on the server. The document is on the client.

Comment: Node.js is executed in the server side, in there doesn't have a document object. This object is available for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `<script>` element **in an HTML document** (and open it in a browser) the entire JavaScript environment is centred about that document.

It goes *browser* ➡ *document*  ➡ *script*

When you run a JS program with Node JS, there is no HTML document.

It goes *Node.js*  ➡ *script*

It isn't centred around an HTML document, so no `document` object is provided for you.

You could create one using a DOM library, but you are not running your script inside one.